# Black screen on iOS Simulator Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Tried

- Uninstalling then reinstalling Xcode
- reset content & setting on simulator
- crying
- rebooting simulator
- simulating pressing home on simulator
- beta & release version of Xcode
- different device simulators
- starting a new project from scratch and running

Problem I launch my app and it runs, I know this cos I see the log output of a print() in the console. However the simulators screen is blank, just black. No UI at all. I can eliminate my app being the problem as When I press (simulate pressing) home it should show me the springboard but its blank (black screen). I reset content & settings. Blank.

anyone able to help?

Additional:

I have completely deleted Xcode, all traces of it from the Mac. Then reinstalled it. Started a new project and (as before blank screen). However this time I notice an error alert.

```
Rountined
App quit Unexpectedly
```

Google finds nothing to suggest what this is or if its related to my issue. However the log file is this, any one able to diagnose the issue?

```
Process:               routined [1045]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/libexec/routined
Identifier:            routined
Version:               413.0.10
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [1039]
Responsible:           routined [1045]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-11-14 12:03:49.450 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.2 (16C41b)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        EB6CBF9E-B878-C122-2B34-BA3ED088512F


Time Awake Since Boot: 1900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        5  Dispatch queue: RTMigrationManager-0x7fd26d50fe00

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
CoreSimulator 338.10 - Device: iPhone 7 Plus - Runtime: iOS 10.2 (14C5062c) - DeviceType: iPhone 7 Plus

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001138f938a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001138f87d7 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f130d24 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f1301a1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1345
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f12fa04 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010e6e98c0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010e6e979b -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
7   libcoreroutine.dylib            0x000000010e388c31 -[RTLifeCycleManager start] + 1124
8   routined                        0x000000010e2d6ecc 0x10e2d6000 + 3788
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001135d268d start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000113901e5a kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011357dc37 _dispatch_mgr_wait_for_event + 79
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000113577a81 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 248
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000113577883 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001139014e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000113935791 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001139351ed start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:: Dispatch queue: RTDefaultsManager-0x7fd26d50ec80-ServiceQueue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000113900cb6 __psynch_mutexwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000113935f6a _pthread_mutex_lock_wait + 100
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f0e8858 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyDictionary] + 312
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f0e854c -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyValueForKey:] + 60
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f1cf045 -[CFPrefsSource copyValueForKey:] + 53
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f1f5640 __76-[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:]_block_invoke + 32
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f20a702 __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 322
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f209f09 normalizeQuintuplet + 329
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f20a5b8 -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 104
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f1f55a6 -[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:] + 310
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010e6cc69b -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) objectForKey:] + 43
11  libcoreroutine.dylib            0x000000010e386602 -[RTDefaultsManager _objectForKey:] + 169
12  libcoreroutine.dylib            0x000000010e38612b __34-[RTDefaultsManager objectForKey:]_block_invoke + 30
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011358912e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000113571d3f _dispatch_non_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 119
15  libcoreroutine.dylib            0x000000010e3860b8 -[RTDefaultsManager objectForKey:] + 225
16  libcoreroutine.dylib            0x000000010e3f3530 __62-[RTRoomSenseManager updateValueForKey:expectedClass:handler:]_block_invoke + 68
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000113567808 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011358912e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011356e4cf _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1018
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011356ec9f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1118
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011356f047 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 376
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001135709dc _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 506
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000113570782 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 113
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000113935712 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001139351ed start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:: Dispatch queue: RTDefaultsManager-0x7fd26d50ec80-ServiceQueue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000113900cb6 __psynch_mutexwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000113935f6a _pthread_mutex_lock_wait + 100
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f0e8858 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyDictionary] + 312
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f0e854c -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyValueForKey:] + 60
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f1cf045 -[CFPrefsSource copyValueForKey:] + 53
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f1f5640 __76-[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:]_block_invoke + 32
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f20a702 __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 322
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f209f09 normalizeQuintuplet + 329
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f20a5b8 -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 104
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x000000010f1f55a6 -[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:] + 310
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x000000010e6cc69b -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) objectForKey:] + 43
11  libcoreroutine.dylib            0x000000010e386602 -[RTDefaultsManager _objectForKey:] + 169
12  libcoreroutine.dylib            0x000000010e38612b __34-[RTDefaultsManager objectForKey:]_block_invoke + 30
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011358912e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000113571d3f _dispatch_non_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 119
15  libcoreroutine.dylib            0x000000010e3860b8 -[RTDefaultsManager objectForKey:] + 225
16  libcoreroutine.dylib            0x000000010e3ebc16 __76-[RTPredictionControllerRoomAssist updateValueForKey:expectedClass:handler:]_block_invoke + 83
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000113567808 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011358912e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011356e4cf _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1018
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011356ec9f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1118
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011356f047 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 376
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001135709dc _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 506
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000113570782 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 113
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000113935712 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001139351ed start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: RTMigrationManager-0x7fd26d50fe00
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000113900dd6 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000113938787 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000011367afd7 abort + 129
3   libcoreroutine.dylib            0x000000010e455926 -[RTMigrationManager abortDueToFatalMigrationError] + 247
4   libcoreroutine.dylib            0x000000010e45560e __48-[RTMigrationManager _finishMigrationWithError:]_block_invoke.174 + 290
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000113567808 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011358912e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011356e4cf _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1018
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011356ec9f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1118
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011356f047 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 376
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001135709dc _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 506
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000113570782 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 113
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000113935712 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001139351ed start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001139014e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000113935791 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001139351ed start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001139014e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000113935791 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001139351ed start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x000070000f1b5b98  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000004703  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x000070000f1b5bc0  rsp: 0x000070000f1b5b98
   r8: 0x000000000000000a   r9: 0x00007fd26d7533f0  r10: 0x000000000c000000  r11: 0x0000000000000202
  r12: 0x000000010ec1bd20  r13: 0x000000010ec1bd20  r14: 0x000070000f1b6000  r15: 0x000000010ec1eac0
  rip: 0x0000000113900dd6  rfl: 0x0000000000000202  cr2: 0x0000000116978000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
     ...
********(REMOVED THIS SECTION TO FIT POST UNDER THE 30,000 CHARACTER LIMIT)

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 1541
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=135.2M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=135.2M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=62.3M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=62.3M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
Dispatch continuations            8192K        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
MALLOC                            41.5M       20 
MALLOC guard page                   48K       10 
SQLite page cache                   64K        2 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        9 
Stack                             11.1M        9 
VM_ALLOCATE                         20K        3 
__DATA                            14.5M      207 
__LINKEDIT                        31.4M      313 
__TEXT                           104.3M      166 
__UNICODE                          556K        2 
mapped file                       25.1M        8 
shared memory                       32K        5 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            293.0M      745 

Model: iMac11,3, BootROM IM112.0057.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core i3, 3.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 1.59f2
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 5670, ATI Radeon HD 5670, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435434473353313333394D2E43313646314B
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435434473353313333394D2E43313646314B
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435434473353313333394D2E43313646314B
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435434473353313333394D2E43313646314B
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x8F), Atheros 9280: 4.0.74.0-P2P
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.2d9, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST31000528AS, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5680H
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: yeah sorry was last thing i tried before posting question. forgot to add to the list. will update question now. thanks

Comment: no only blank screen still. I dont even see apple logo if i reboot it

Comment: Okay, so all this blank and black stuff turns out to be a red herring. The simulator is crashing. Report it to Apple.

Comment: @matt will do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. I updated to the latest Version 8.2 beta (8C30a) and all works. Not really an answer as still don't know the cause.

Comment: It's a good enough answer for me! Glad to hear they fixed this.

Comment: it happended to me the moment i ran Xcode 10 beta 2(all the iPhone plus simulators only), now installing beta 3. Praying that your answer works for me

Answer (score 1):

I have the same - everything works but screen is black. Answer is very simple:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *loadView;
```

**Avoid to use** property with name **loadView**